# Unity Facebook SDK score posting failing with FB.API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to post score on facebook in Unity using facebook SDK. I am using the following code:

```
FB.Login("email,publish_actions,user_friends", LoginCallback);

var scoreData = 
new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"score", score.ToString()}};
        
FB.API ("/me/scores", HttpMethod.POST, LogCallback, scoreData);
```

In LogCallback, I am getting the following error:

```
10-29 20:16:15.760: E/Unity(15752): You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.
10-29 20:16:15.760: E/Unity(15752): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/me/scores
```

Regarding permissions, I am seeing the following on developers.facebook.com

[image: permissions image]

I dont see

```
publish_actions permission
```

there.

If I try to add this permission, it wants me to upload APK and submit for review. Am I missing something? Can someone guide me? Thank you

Comment: Are you able to solve this problem?